# How can I get the product of two lists?

Tags: python

On python, I can use the `combinations` function from `itertools` to get all the possible couples in a list. But is there a way to get all the combinations possible taking one element in a list and the other in another list?

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5]
```

Is there a function that would return

```
(1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are look for the "Cartesian Product":

[`itertools.product(list1, list2, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

#### Example

```
from itertools import product

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5]

>>> print list(product(l1, l2))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```